# Can't decode NSString well

Tags: ios, utf-8, encode, latin1

I had my server encoding in ISO-8859-1 and decided to chango into UTF-8. The problem is that the filenames creates in ISO now crashes because I change the encoding type in my code. I try to connect with an iOS app and show the directories and files, the news are shown well but the olds with ISO not.

How can I detect if the filename is in one or other encoding to process in the right way each one? Because now, the filename in ISO it can be represent in UTF-8 but the string to access is not the same. (Ex: %E1p%F1 --> %C3%A1p%C3%B1)

I try this, but it doesn't work:

```
NSString *isoL = [item.href stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
char const *iso2utf = [isoL UTF8String];
NSString *utf = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:iso2utf encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the server declare the content encoding of the response, much like how HTTP does.

I don't believe it's possible to auto-detect ISO-8859-1/UTF-8 text encoding.